I am unable to serve my AppSail Application in Local Environment
When I try to run my Catalyst AppSail Application using the CLI command "catalyst serve", I am getting the following error. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

✖ No free ports between 3000 and 3010. AppSail needs the ports within
this range to function properly


From the error screenshot you have shared us, we can see you are facing this CLI error because the port from 3000 to 3010 is not available. In order to resolve this issue, we would suggest you kill any process that are running from the ports 3000 to 3010 using the command "kill ".
You can get the PID for those process using the command "lsof -i:3000-3010 -P -n". Once you have killed those running process you can try running your catalyst application using the command "catalyst serve" and let us know if you are still facing the same issue.
